# Javascript Events building up

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Having an issue with delegating events. It seems, as I click on my elements, they are stacking each time. The first click will work once, the second will click twice and so forth as many times as I've clicked. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's an actual snippet of the script:

```
$.fn.multiselect = function() {
    
    $this       = this;
    current     = $(this).next('.multilist');
    list        = [];
    count = 0;
    
    $this.click(function() {
        $(current).toggle();
        $(current).find('a').click(function() {
            event.stopPropagation()
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            console.log(count++)
            return false;
        })
        return false;
    });

}
```

Below is the console output of count.
The events to return this (note the console.log is within the inner click event:

1. Clicked `$this` to show the hidden element (current) with `toggle()`
2. Clicked `$this` again to hide the element (current) with `toggle()`
3. Clicked `$this` another time show element (current) with `toggle()`

4. Clicked current a element

[image]

The count was at 3, which will increase as I click on `$this`.
Not sure why this is happening, any help here would be excellent.

After clicking:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `undelegate` is inside of the body click function and is targeted using `$(this)`

```
$('body').click(function() {

  $(current).css({
    display: 'none'
  });

  $(this).undelegate(this, 'click');
  return false;
})
```

It would be best to save your element, then use it to undelegate:

```
var $this = $(this);

$this.delegate('.filter', 'click', function(e) {

// ...

$('body').click(function() {

  $(current).css({
    display: 'none'
  });

  $this.undelegate('.filter', 'click');
  return false;
})
```

---

Update: Your update has a nested click function within a click function... it will just keep binding click events to the link. And in this case, I'm not sure why the `current` variable is being saved but I can't tell exactly what the code is doing, so maybe an isolated demo on jsFiddle.net would help. But for now try removing the nested click function:

```
$.fn.multiselect = function() {

    $(this).click(function(event) {
      $(this).next('.multilist')
        .toggle()
        .find('a').toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the reason. I modified my current script so scale it back in hope to find where the issue lies.  But it seems to be related to the events generated from the outer click. I'll update the script with some output to show what I am getting.

Comment: I've updated my answer... but I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am basically creating a pop/drop menu with selectable elements. So clicking a link displays the selectable list, clicking an element in that list, selects it (or applies the active class). In my revised post, theres a small image showing the list with the elements (which are dates) and the darker ones are active. Hope that clarifies a bit more - much appreciated on your help here.